# Get maven deploy to create a snapshot tag

Tags: maven

What would be a good way to get 'mvn deploy' for snapshot deployment to create a snapshot tag(x.y.x-20110304.mmhhss-1) in git using the snapshot version(x.y.x-20110304.mmhhss-1) identifier created by maven, release plugin creates release tags. I would like a tag for snapshots.

Thanks

-am

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported by Maven (Snapshot) repositories. Snapshots are designed to be throw-away or development builds. Repository managers like Nexus often have background jobs which purge old snapshots.

The purpose of tagging is to be able to reproduce that binary again. If you really care, perhaps you should release more often?

Finally, some version control systems impose a rather stupid overhead on tagging operations (updating each file in the repository.... Clearcase, CVS, etc). This has traditionally discouraged tagging during a CI build (which would typically generate the snapshot release).